# Converter tipo genérico para especifico no DB set

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Estou criando uma web api utilizando o .net 5

O objetivo da aplicação é fazer um cadastro simples de usuário, e futuramente outros tipos de cadastro

Criei uma interface genérica de CRUD para ser usada em todas as outras interfaces especificas

```
public interface IbaseRepository
{
    void Criar<T>(T obj);

    void Editar<T>(T obj);

    void Deletar<T>(T obj);
}
```

Interface de Usuário

```
public interface IUsuarioRepository : IbaseRepository
{
    ICollection<Usuario> ObterTodos();
}
```

Minha classe de Usuário ainda esta incompleta, mas mesmo assim vou colocar aqui

```
[Table("Cliente")]
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    [Column("cd_id", TypeName = "numeric(10)")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Historico")]
    public ICollection<Historico> Historico { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Historico")] 
    public Historico HistoricoId { get; set; }
}
```

A minha duvida é nesse ponto aqui

Como a interface recebe como parametro um tipo generico, eu não consigo passar para a função de add pois ela espera um objeto do tipo Usuario. **Como eu faço para converter o tipo generico em tipo especifico**

Obs: Estou usando o **Entity Framework Core V 5.0.8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua interface tem que ser genérica...

```
public interface IbaseRepository<T>
{
    void Criar(T obj);

    void Editar(T obj);

    void Deletar(T obj);
}
```

E depois você passa o tipo na herança:

```
public interface IUsuarioRepository : IbaseRepository<Usuario>
{
    ICollection<Usuario> ObterTodos();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Rovann

Comment: Mas uma coisa que deveria ser ressaltada nessa sua resposta, é que a classe de Usuário ira substituir a letra T pela classe

public void Editar(Usuario obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }